# Automapper - Dictionary to Object Mapping not working?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, automapper

I'm trying to convert a dictionary to an object. I've tried the following but it doesnt work:

```
public class FormField 
{
   public string FieldName { get; set;}
   public string FieldValue { get; set;}
}

var formData = new List<FormField>
{
    new FormField {FieldName = "date", FieldValue = "2017-09-14"},
    new FormField {FieldName = "name", FieldValue = "Job blogs"},
    new FormField {FieldName = "isenabled", FieldValue = "true"}
};

public class MyViewModel 
{
  [Required]
  public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.now;

  [Required]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public boolean IsEnabled { get; set; }

  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Titles 
  {
    get
    {
        var options = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem(){ Value = "Mr", Text = "Mr" },
            new SelectListItem(){ Value = "Mrs", Text = "Mrs" }                    
        };
        return options;
    }
  } 
}
```

Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {});
}
```

Code

```
var viewModel = Mapper.Map<MyViewModel>(formData.ToDictionary(x => x.FieldName, x => (object) x.FieldValue))
```

Note I'm using automapper 5.0.2.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: @Jan_V No errors - `viewModel` is empty i.e. no values are set.

Comment: If I alter your code as given so that it actually compiles this works fine in a .NET 4.5, Automapper 5.0.2 console application...

Comment: I also worked .net4.5 AutoMapper 5.0.2. model is fiiled

Comment: Ok looks like the issue is case sensative. dictionary names are all lower case and the object properties are Pascal case. How can I force automapper to ignore case?

Comment: You cannot. You have to do it yourself when building the dictionary.

Comment: I thought by default Automapper was case **in**sensitive and you had to explicitly state anything different. Am I mistaken? Aside from that, does this link help? https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#naming-conventions

Comment: It is, but this is special :) See [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/1313).

Answer (score 1):

It works for me with the latest. Upgrade :)

Comment: And I'm not even sure the version is responsible. I would bet you're not even executing this exact code. Because it doesn't compile :) So run the code you posted, not smth else.